# GitHub API - Finding what languages does the repository is using

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github

I am Using GitHub API to list all the public repository of the user. But now i want to see what language they use in the repository and call it through API. I did lot of research and looked into API but can't find anything around. Later i want to display this information into Graph.

Please point me to the right direction or any tutorial, or any help is much appreciated.

Please note i am using Angularjs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `languages` endpoint for repositories, documented here: [List languages](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages).

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/GeekOnGadgets/AngularGalaxyUI/languages
{
  "JavaScript": 142531,
  "CSS": 205009
}
```

According to the manual, “The value on the right of a language is the number of bytes of code written in that language.”